# Akita and Angular Error: StaticInjector and NullInjector Store, Query

Tags: angular, akita

I got into an error with Akita state management implementation on the Angular project. I will just provide a short answer in order for some people like me could resolve this issue.

There is no clear understanding of this in Akita docs and examples.

```
export interface ItemState extends EntityState<Item> {}

@StoreConfig({ name: 'items' })
export class ItemsStore extends EntityStore<ItemState> {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

I receive error:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ItemsService -> ItemsStore]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ItemsStore!

It should work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not mentioned in docs, but in order for this to work we just need to add provideIn: 'root'

```
export interface ItemState extends EntityState<Item> {}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
@StoreConfig({ name: 'items' })
export class ItemsStore extends EntityStore<ItemState> {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Same is for ItemsQuery. Hope this was helpful for somebody

Comment: You are a lifesaver sir! Spend ages on this, going through docs, etc - could not find anything of relevance. Now that I saw this answer, it is in their sample code, just hard to see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-todos-app?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftodos%2Fstate%2Ftodos.store.ts

Comment: This should be marked as the answer by the way as it does answer the question directly

Answer (score 2):

I suppose ItemService is a service made by you, nad you just forgot to add a provider for the same. either you can change the @Injectable() decorator to so goven below.

```
@Injector({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

or you can add the service as a provider to the module that you are using the service inside.

it'll be like,

```
@ngModule({
...,
providers: [ItemService,...],
...
})
```

Don't forget to import the service in the module.

Comment: I'm not talking about service, but more for Store and Query. And if you used Injectable no need to add it to ngModule providers. You will have a lot of stores and queries it would be a mess to have all this in providers.

Comment: Whatever you are talking about, the error message you given occurs when a service is neither provided in root nor a provider in some module.